# The Google search widget leaks memory in side system server. How to resolve this memory leak from platform side ( from framwork side)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, java-memory-leaks

I observed memory leak inside a system server when we use the Google search widget on home screen. The Google widget is updating on every click on home button and holding muliple reference of class **com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl**

Check below analysis report from Memory anaylsis Tool.

> One instance of
>   "**com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl**" loaded
>   by"**dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c1d220**" occupies 47,168,416
>   (**65.38%**)bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance
>   of"**com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl**" loaded
>   by"**dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x12c1d220**".

[Heap dump Analysis MAT screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9JqP.png)

Steps to reproduce the issue.:

1. Do factory data reset.
2. Complete setupwizard with Google login account.
3. Don't disconnect internet connection.
4. Clear all apps from the recent tab.
5. Press HOME key >> wait for 1sec >> Press Recent app key >> Wait for 1sec >> Press HOME key wait for 1 sec.
6. Repeat step 5 for multiple times ( 100 times ) and observe the system server heap memory with below command

adb shell dumpsys meminfo

I observed increase in "Heap Size" and "Heap Alloc" column from "Dalvik Heap"

Find below heap size before and after.

[system_server memoryinfo details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZpSX.png)

**If I disabled google search app then the system server memory leak was not observed.**

I am new in memory leak issue debugging. Help to conclude on, 
who one is eating heap size in side system server and why?

Thanks